# out of memory multiple photo upload

Tags: android, image, upload, imageview

I am trying to upload few photos from my android application to the server. I am getting the out of memory error. My code for image selection is as follows

code triggered when select image button is clicked

---

```
public void triggerImageSelection(View view) {
    int triggeringView = Integer.parseInt((String) view.getTag());
    Log.v(DBUG, "tag of the view:" + triggeringView);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            triggeringView);
}
```

---

onActivityResult part of the code is as follows:

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.v(DBUG, "request code:: " + requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            filePaths[0] = getPath(data.getData());
            File filewe = new File(getPath(data.getData()));
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(data
                    .getData()));
            mAdImage1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            if (filewe != null)
                Log.v(DBUG, "got file" + filePaths[0]);
            mAdImage1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        break;
```

---

the getPath(); function returns the file path and is as follows

---

```
private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

---

i have four buttons for selecting four images. It works fine for the first time but in second time it shows out of memory exception. How can i tackle with this?

Answer (score 3):

While reading from the file try to reduce the quality of the image as follows

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 6; 
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(data.getData()),options); 
mAdImage1.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
bitmap1.recycle();
bitmap1=null;
```

If the problem still persists, use `android:largeHeap="true"`  in the application tag of manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is everytime you are creating a new Bitmap and Old Bitmaps are still there in memory. GC will collect it whenever it decides.

In case of Bitmaps its recommended to notify GC to garbage collect the objects. I suggest below approach. Hope This Helps!

1. Cache the bitmaps which are shown currently. If you already have cached bitmap, do not call BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(data.getData())); Instead, use cached one.
2. Whenever activity is destroyed, recycle the bitmaps as shown below. This method needs to be called from onDestroy method of activity. destroy means we do not need the bitmap now.
   Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()

   ```
   public void recycleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
           if (bitmap != null) {
               bitmap.recycle();
               bitmap = null;
               System.gc();
           }
       }
   ```